# Exception: "Name Not Found" When connecting to TIBCO EMS using Tibco Web Messaging

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-ems, kaazing

I am trying to connect Tibco Web Messaging (TWM) to Tibco EMS. But I get NameNotFoundException on the ConnectionFactory. Below is  the log.

```
ERROR Error starting Gateway: caught exception java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext cannot be cast to javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
at com.kaazing.gateway.jms.server.service.StompJmsService.initHandler(StompJmsService.java:103)
at com.kaazing.gateway.jms.server.service.AbstractStompService.init(AbstractStompService.java:210)
at com.kaazing.gateway.jms.server.service.AbstractStompFanoutService.init(AbstractStompFanoutService.java:87)
at com.kaazing.gateway.jms.server.service.StompJmsService.init(StompJmsService.java:91)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.context.resolve.DefaultServiceContext.init(DefaultServiceContext.java:697)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.Launcher.initInternal(Launcher.java:54)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.Launcher.init(Launcher.java:33)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.impl.GatewayImpl.launch(GatewayImpl.java:291)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.GatewayCommandProcessor.launchGateway(GatewayCommandProcessor.java:98)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.GatewayCommandProcessor.launchGateway(GatewayCommandProcessor.java:43)
at com.kaazing.gateway.server.Main.main(Main.java:34)
INFO  Stopping server
INFO  Stopping management
```

Has anyone got the same error.

Thanks, Naveen

Comment: Kaazing document has a reference to this error, I tried doing the same. But no help. http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/3.5/integration-jms/p_jms_integrate_tshoot.html#problem1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no factories in the factories.conf file. Using Tibco Administration tool, was able to create a factory using the command.

create factory GenericConnectionFactory generic URL=tcp://7222

This did the trick.

Naveen

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Tibco JMS for the first time, you need to create QueueConnectionFactory and TopicConnectionFactory. Make sure you add special character ">" in your ems queues.conf file.

Command to create Queue:

create factory QueueConnectionFactory queue URL=tcp://7222

Command to create Topic:

create factory TopicConnectionFactory topic URL=tcp://7222

Comment: This helped me to solve my problem. After sending the commands I opened the `factories.conf` file (in...`tibco\ems\<version>\ ` ) and changed the URLs from `tcp://7222` to `tcp://localhost:7222`.